# Sound editing and equalizer on python

Tags: python, macos, audio, osx-mountain-lion, frequency

Im currently using [pyglet](http://www.pyglet.org/) as my sound library on python,

The library is great but it does not contain an important feature i really need:

Frequency control while playing a certain song (lets say .mp3),

Meaning, I want to lower the bass frequency or raise the higher frequencies while playing

a certain song.

And it should have a player which can play songs from a certain location in the song,

Play couple of .mp3's together and can pause/stop when needed (pyglet has these options)

Is there a python sound library which holds these capabilities?

Im using mac os 10.8